# Expandable list view

Tags: android, android-activity, textview, expandablelistview

i am newbie in android development..
i m using expandable `listview`,
In each row of listview i have `3 textview` and `1 button` ,on button click
i want selected child data to be on another `activity`
with his `Group header name` is that possible in `Expandable list view` 
if its then how ?
please help...

Comment: I think no one will write the code for you, so show us some code you already got and where you got problems.

Comment: is it possible to use the setTag on button click ?

Comment: You might want to look at Intents to get your thing working.

Comment: you will have to create a custom listview adapter.

Answer (score 3):

**For expandable list just implement following code:**

**ExpandableListDemo.java**

```
  public class ExpandableListDemo extends Activity {

        private ExpandableListView expandableListView;
        private ArrayList<Places> places;
        private PlaceAdapter placeAdapter;
        DisplayMetrics metrics;
        int width;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_expandable_list_demo);
            initUI();

            initData();



            placeAdapter=new PlaceAdapter(places, this);

            expandableListView.setAdapter(placeAdapter);

            expandableListView.setIndicatorBounds(width - GetDipsFromPixel(30), width - GetDipsFromPixel(5));
        }

        private void initData() {
            places=new ArrayList<Places>();
            Places place1=new Places();
            place1.setName("Maharashtra");
            String [] city1={"Pune","Mumbai","Nagpur","Aurangabad","Nasik"};
            place1.setCities(city1);

            Places place2=new Places();
            place2.setName("Gujrat");
            String [] city2={"Surat","Bhavnagar","Ahmedabad","Vadodara","Rajkot"};
            place2.setCities(city2);

            Places place3=new Places();
            place3.setName("AndhraPradesh");
            String [] city3={ "Hyderabad", "Visakhapatnam", "Vijayawada", "Guntur", "Rajahmundr" };
            place3.setCities(city3);

            Places place4=new Places();
            place4.setName("Karnataka");
            String [] city4={"Bagalkote","Bangalore","Belgaum","Bellary"};
            place4.setCities(city4);

            places.add(place1);
            places.add(place2);
            places.add(place3);
            places.add(place4);

            metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            width = metrics.widthPixels;
        }

        private void initUI() {
            expandableListView=(ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.places_listview);
        }

        public int GetDipsFromPixel(float pixels)
        {
         // Get the screen's density scale
         final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
         // Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
         return (int) (pixels * scale + 0.5f);
        }
    }
```

Custom place adapter:

```
 public class PlaceAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

        private ArrayList<Places> placesList;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public PlaceAdapter(ArrayList<Places> placesList,Context context) {
            this.placesList=placesList;
            mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }
        //return child at specific position.
        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return placesList.get(groupPosition).getCities();
        }

        //return child id for specific position.
        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        //return child view at specific position.
        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ChildHolder childHolder;
            if(convertView==null) {
                childHolder=new ChildHolder();
                convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item,null);
                childHolder.childTv=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_chid_item);
                convertView.setTag(childHolder);
            }else{
                childHolder=(ChildHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            childHolder.childTv.setText("-->"+placesList.get(groupPosition).getCities()[childPosition]);
            return convertView;
        }

        //return number of child for specific parent.
        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return placesList.get(groupPosition).getCities().length;
        }

        //get parent at specific position.
        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return placesList.get(groupPosition);
        }

        //return number of parent items.
        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return placesList.size();
        }

        //return parent id for specific position
        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        //return parent view for specific position
        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ParentHolder parentHolder;

            if(convertView==null) {

                parentHolder=new ParentHolder();

                convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_item,null);

                parentHolder.parentTv=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_parent_item);

                convertView.setTag(parentHolder);

            }else{
                parentHolder=(ParentHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
                parentHolder.parentTv.setText(placesList.get(groupPosition).getName());
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return false;
        }

        private class ParentHolder {
            TextView parentTv;
        }

        private class ChildHolder {
            TextView childTv;
        }

    }
```

Places model:

```
public class Places {
    private String name;
    private String [] cities;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String[] getCities() {
        return cities;
    }
    public void setCities(String[] cities) {
        this.cities = cities;
    }


}
```

**activity_expandable_list_demo.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/places_listview"
        android:groupIndicator="@drawable/arrow_selector"
        ></ExpandableListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**child_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txt_chid_item"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**parent_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txt_parent_item"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ExpandableListDemo"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_expandable_list_demo" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

[image: Pluse Icon]

[image: Minus Icon]

(Use above icon in your drawable)
I hope this code will more helpful to implement expandable list view

Answer (score 0):

This will help u out:-

-------------in expandable activity------------------

```
private void loadHosts(final ArrayList<Parent> newParents) {
        if (newParents == null)
            return;
        parents = newParents;
        Log.d("StackOverFlow", "parents arrived: " + newParents.size());
        if (this.getExpandableListAdapter() == null) {
            mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(this, parents, R.layout.adapter_horizontal);
            this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else
            ((MyExpandableListAdapter) getExpandableListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

//--------------custom adapter---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.merck.activity.R;

public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Parent> parents;
    private int parentLayoutResource;

    /**
     * A simple adapter which maintains an ArrayList of photo resource Ids. Each
     * photo is displayed as an image. This adapter supports clearing the list
     * of photos and adding a new photo.
     */
    public MyExpandableListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Parent> parents, int parentLayoutResource) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.parents = parents;
        this.parentLayoutResource = parentLayoutResource;

    }

    ImageView img;

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView) {
        final Parent parent = parents.get(groupPosition);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(parentLayoutResource, null, false);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.top)).setText(parent.getName());
        img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrow);



        if(!isExpanded){
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_gray );
        }
        else
        {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_gray_down );
        }
        // CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)
        // convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        // checkbox.setChecked(parent.isChecked());
        // if (parent.isChecked())
        // convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
        // else
        // convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
        // checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckUpdateListener(parent));
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {

        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    };

    private EditText childText1;
    private EditText childText2;

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parentView) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_profile, parentView, false);
        childText1 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_password);
        childText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                MedListManager.getInstance().setChildText1(arg0.toString());
                System.out.println("!!!!! setChildText1"+arg0.toString());

            }
        });
        childText2 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_confirm_pass);
        childText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                MedListManager.getInstance().setChildText2(arg0.toString());
                System.out.println("!!!!! setChildText2"+arg0.toString());

            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return parents.get(groupPosition).getChildren().get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return parents.get(groupPosition).getChildren().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return parents.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return parents.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return ((parents == null) || parents.isEmpty());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return true;
    }




}
```