# Expandable list view with forms

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I've been asked to make an app that has a very VERY long data input form (we're talking around 50 fields here!). Thats a design constraint and there is absolutely no way for me to work around that.

What I'm trying to do is to display the form in a way thats easier on the user. My idea was to break the form into sections and somehow use an expandable list view to display the form. The list group would be the section name and the list items would be the input forms.

My problem is that since the form can contain different types of input fields (checkboxes, radio buttons, textfields etc) and since I'm new to android programming, I dont really know how to do this. All the online tutorials I can find are about simple uniform expandable lists. Can someone suggest me a good tutorial or an alternative to my idea?

Answer (score 0):

What you're going to need to do is extend your BaseExpandableListAdapter and customize it to display all the various layout options.  Specifically, it's going to be the getChildView() method that you'll have to do the most work in.   Do some searches for customizing or extending the BaseExpandableListAdapter and you should find plenty to go by.

Also, take a look at the example from the SDK:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html

Edit: Link not available

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using ExpandableListView as is, but create your own xml layout file for each list 'child' row, putting the field name and then a text input field for the value into it.

Have alook at this page where the author shows how you can put a 'checkbox' next to each list items row:

http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2010/12/expandable-list-and-checkboxes.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use child layout view for achiving this.

follow below link and find the code,Inflating only one text view but u can inflate the complete layout(I personally used that thing in my code).

[Expandable list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814756/expandable-list-view)